# what´s the purpose of ProjectDependencies in VS-solution-file

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I read [this post on the contents of a solution file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629981/whats-the-purpose-of-this-string-in-my-visual-studio-sln-file), but still have no clue about the actual purpose of dependencies provided within a solution-file rather than within the project-file itself.

It seems there are two ways of having project 2 depending on project 1:

1. add a project-reference from p2 to p1. This will alter the csproj-file for p2 by introducing a `ProjectReference` to p1.csproj, but won´t change the solution, as far as I understand.
2. add an assembly-reference from p2 to p1. Thill will also alter the csproj-file by using a `Reference` to a compiled assembly (dll). However, it **also** adds a `ProectDependency` into the solution-file, which I do not understand. Why is this second entry within the solution needed in this case? Isn´t the assembly-reference provided within the csproj-file for p2 sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's purely historical. The new project files don't really need it anymore, but the `.sln` file format predates msbuild and thus the solution file has some duplication.

It's used to define the build order, which becomes more important when you have ancient project types in your solution, as these won't be able to declare build order. It's also used to declare and validate build order between unrelated projects (e.g., project that don't reference each other), without the IDE having to load & parse all the projects.

Your second case is one of those cases where the solution file keeps track of build order. It then knows it needs to build P1 prior to P2. Without the solution level reference that information would be lost. It's quite clever that this is automatically detected and added, in the past you needed to manually define such build-order-dependencies.

At compile time the `.sln` is transformed into an msbuild file which then orchestrates the build. (see [an example here](https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/b2262c96c2c1ee7d1180e55514aa8fed)). [You can set an environment variable to generate yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5237948/736079).

### <TL;DR>

The solution file is ancient and has some artefacts left over from pre msbuild. Some things just need to be there for 'reasons'.

If they were to build VS from scratch, the solution file would look very different.

Comment: "It's quite clever that this is automatically detected and added" You mean when I add a reference to the assembly within VS, don´t you?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.